# Navigation - image on a:hover and a:selected

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, hover

I'm trying to add a "folder" (don't know what to call it) behind the items I hover on in my navigation menu and also stays there on the selected page. 
You can see the image here:

[image: Hover background]

But since this is a one size image, it's to big for some of my items.

How do I make this work the best possible way? Should I use som jQuery or just stick to CSS?

You can see what I've done so far on: "*deleted my link, after the solution was found*"

Hope you can give me some helpful answers. :)

Comment: Cut that image into three pieces, the left, the right, and the repeatable-middle.

Comment: I'd go for nine pieces, to make it adjustable in height as well? Or just resize the image to fit !

Comment: @adeneo he's right, the most dynamic solution is 9 pieces.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - As a sidenote, that's actually how Google makes some of their UI stuff, with nine pieces for a small button etc. four corners, four sides, and a center piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the `background-image` to reflect only the orange gradient (without the curves at the top corners).
- Use CSS `border-radius` for the rounded corners at the bottom.
- Cut the top corners curve to a seperate image and use CSS' `:before` and `:after` to place the image in the left and right corners accordingly.

Something like:

```
#nav a:hover
    {
    background-image: url('orange_gradient.png'); /* could be 1px wide */
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    }

#nav a:hover:before
    {
    content: url('curve.png');
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
    }

#nav a:hover:after
    {
    content: url('curve.png');
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this now. As you can see on the site. However, my curves just wind up on top of each other. And the home button is acting wierd. 

But thanks a lot for the answer. It seems like the right way to go.

Comment: Ahh, the inline-block that you just added helped.

Comment: I believe you'll have to tweak it more, but i think it's the cleanest and most flexible way.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not quite sure on how to move the curves to the sides properly, since it's not the same distance for each of the items.

Comment: I changed the `CSS` a bit, added `left` and `right` attributes, so you need to use the margin-left/right attributes only for the small offset required for each side.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been a big help.

Answer (score 1):

In a word Sliding doors effect

Old but good the original technique

http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors